В ESP32 может проверить наличие подключённого по Wi-Fi устройства
Есть ESP32, которая управляется по Wi-Fi при помощи библиотеки RemoteXY и соответствующего мобильного приложения. Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно добавить в код, чтобы проверять подключена собственно по вайфаю мобила или нет. И если соединение упало, то надо обнулить одну переменную. Код примерно такой:
#define REMOTEXY_MODE__ESP32CORE_WIFI_POINT
#include <WiFi.h>
//-#include <ESP32_Servo.h>
#include <RemoteXY.h>
#include "esp32-hal-ledc.h"

// настройки соединения
#define REMOTEXY_WIFI_SSID "RemoteXY"
#define REMOTEXY_WIFI_PASSWORD "12345678"
#define REMOTEXY_SERVER_PORT 6377

int i,k,t,d;

//-Servo kren;
//-Servo tangaj;

// конфигурация интерфейса
#pragma pack(push, 1)
uint8_t RemoteXY_CONF[] = // 27 bytes
{ 255,3,0,0,0,20,0,16,5,0,5,0,38,2,59,59,2,26,31,4,
0,27,0,9,61,2,26 };

// структура определяет все переменные и события вашего интерфейса управления
struct {

// input variables
int8_t joystick_1_x; // oт -100 до 100
int8_t joystick_1_y; // oт -100 до 100
int8_t rud; // =0..100 положение слайдера

// other variable
uint8_t connect_flag; // =1 if wire connected, else =0

} RemoteXY;
#pragma pack(pop)

/////////////////////////////////////////////
// END RemoteXY include //
/////////////////////////////////////////////

void setup()
{
RemoteXY_Init ();
Serial.begin(115200);



// TODO you setup code

}

void loop()
{
RemoteXY_Handler ();
..........
}

Заранее спасибо.

Предположу что нужно проверять RemoteXY_isConnected() после RemoteXY_Handler () https://github.com/RemoteXY/RemoteXY-Arduino-library/

Спасибо. if (not RemoteXY_isConnected()) {d=0;} вроде работает. Правда почему-то с небольшим запозданием (но это не критично).
